# How can I disable overscrolling in OSX Lion?

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you disable rubber-band scrolling in OS X Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18187/can-you-disable-rubber-band-scrolling-in-os-x-lion)

I'm really frustrated with the way overscrolling works in Lion. It makes working with flexible web applications quite difficult.

Anyway is there a way to disable the over scroll?

Comment: Just out of curiousity: What kind of flexible web applications are you thinking of here?

Comment: like chrome webstore, wikipedia, reddit etc...

Comment: Server side or client side? If the former, try a wrapper-div with `overflow: scroll` and `height: 100%` to disable the rubber-band-effect

Answer (score 1):

This setting perhaps :
[image]
Found in System Preferences => Genral

Comment: I already tried it but doesn't disables the overscrolling :(

Comment: Specific app or system wide ?

Comment: Doesn't affects any applications which support over scrolling.