# How to disable page snipping on Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you disable rubber-band scrolling in OS X Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18187/can-you-disable-rubber-band-scrolling-in-os-x-lion)

One of the "great" features implemented on Mac Os Lion is the fact web frames can be detached and snapped as on IOS when scrolling.

For example when scrolling the page is "detached" and snaps back on scroll release. See the screen shot below :

[image: Screenshot]

As nice as it is, it is also really irritating when working and having to go fast. How to disable this?

Comment: I'm adraid I do not agree with the duplicate part. This is clearly a Chrome issue since added in update 15.xx.xxx released 27/10/2011.

Comment: AFAIK Chrome just implemented standard OS X scrolling behavior. The answers in the duplicate apply.