# How do I find hidden UIScrollView settings in Safari and Lion?

Tags: safari, macos

The question (and answer) [Can you disable rubber-band scrolling in OS X Lion?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18187/can-you-disable-rubber-band-scrolling-in-os-x-lion) is very useful, so I would like to learn how to find these settings.

How can I find out what these variables are so I can turn them off without needing to find a question here one by one?

Comment: This has had some flags as a dupliate, but all the duplicates have been focused on the end result - what to type - as opposed to the process of uncovering hidden defaults. Do we have that question on the site? If so, please flag for removal / merging.